# Can't debug my microsoft teams tab using DevTools

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get console logs from my tab using DevTools in Microsoft Teams. I can open the console, but my logs are not showed and I'm getting the following error instead:

*The Content-Security-Policy directive 'prefetch-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled.*

[image]

I tested my application in Chrome and I can see the logs properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean in the desktop version of Teams, then when you access via DevTools (sounds like this is what you're doing), try choosing All WebContents. Remember, Teams is an electron app historically, so everything is a "web" content - you'll get multiple DevTools windows and you need to find which is the right one for your tab. Screenshot below shows this option.
[image]

But, a better tip, if you're actively developing your tab, is just to run Teams in a browser directly (browse to teams.microsoft.com) - then it's just a single DevTools option and easier to manage.